# Не удаляются куки, с помощью формы

Tags: php

почему, после того, как создать куку и если нажать на выход, то кука не удаляется?

```
<?php error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; char set=utf-8');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if(isset($_POST['login']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && ($_POST['password'])){
    setcookie($_POST['login'], $_POST['email'], time()+3600*24*30, '/');

    echo 'Ваш Логин: ' . $_POST['login'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Ваш Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Ваш Пароль: ' . $_POST['password'] . '<br>';

    echo '
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Выход" name="exit">
        </form>
    ';

    if(isset($_POST['exit'])){
        unset($_COOKIE[$_POST['login']]);
    }
}

?>

<div class="login" style="border: 1px solid; width: 220px; clear: both; overflow: hidden">
<p style="text-align: center;">Вход</p>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div style="clear: both;">
            <span style="float: left">Логин:</span> <input type="text" name="login" style="float: right; width: 150px;">
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;">
            <span style="float: left">Email:</span> <input type="text" name="email" style="float: right; width: 150px;">
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;">
            <span style="float: left">Пароль:</span> <input type="text" name="password" style="float: right; width: 150px;">
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 30px; overflow: hidden">
            <input type="submit" value="Войти" style="float: right;">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Удаляет куки таким вот оброзом ставим отрицательное время, на час назад

```
setcookie("login", "", time() - 3600);
```

Comment: сделал так, всё равно не удаляется if(isset($_POST['exit'])){
  setcookie($_POST['login'], "", time() - 3600);
 }

Comment: сделайте принт если вы там вообще, ` if(isset($_POST['exit'])){ print_r($_POST)`

Comment: такое условие тоже не работает     if(isset($_POST['exit']) && $login == $_POST['login']){

Comment: значит вы передаете что-то не то, отпечатайте в начале файла это `print_r($_POST);` и добавьте , то что вышло в вопрос